# AngularJS Multiple Directive Resource Contention

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I am trying to build a directive with angular.

Here is the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/KbccCT?p=preview)

I wanted to split it into 3 directives:

- Top, grand-parent directive.  - many **DAYS**
- Middle, created with ng-repeat - one **DAY**
- Bottom, created with ng-repeat - many **TIME BLOCKS**

`angular
.directive('dateTimeBlocks', [function dateTimeBlocksDirective () {}])    .directive('dayBlock', [function dayDirective () {}])
.directive('timeBlock', [function timeBlockDirective () {}])`

I wanted to create middle and bottom directives with
isolated scopes and only pass the data that I want to modify inside.

But it seems to unable to compile 
"Multiple directives [dateBlock, dateBlock] asking for template on: ..."

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This line causes that error:

```
<date-block data-date-block="datePeriod"></date-block>
```

The reason is a combination of factors. First, AngularJS always normalizes directive declarations, so `data-date-block` (or `x-date-block`, `data:date:block` etc.) is actually treated as `date-block`. Therefore, the above line is equivalent to:

```
<date-block date-block="datePeriod"></date-block>
```

Now, the `dateBlock` directive is declared with `restrict: 'AE'`, so it can be applied as either an element or attribute. Therefore, the above line resulting in AngularJS applying the `dateBlock` directive to the element **twice**.

That per se doesn't cause the error, but `dateBlock` declares a template and AngularJS doesn't allow an element to have 2 templates (it doesn't make sense anyway, which template should AngularJS choose?), so it throws an error.

There are several ways to fix it.

1. Restrict the directive to `E` so that AngularJS doesn't treat `data-date-block` as a directive.
2. Rename the isolated scope property `dateBlock` to something else.
3. Use the attribute form of the directive and use `<div>` for the element form. Like this: `<div data-date-block="datePeriod"></div>`

Comment: wow, what an overlook. i was trying every combination of directive properties imaginable :s Thank you very much for finding this out! :] the error message for me was misleading, i could not have figure that one out

Answer (score 4):

Just in case anyone else comes here, you can also get this error if you have a template and templateUrl in the same directive.

i.e:

```
...
        template: '<div>Hello world</div>',
        templateUrl: "MyTemplate.html",
...
```

Hope that helps someone, the error message doesn't immediately point you to this.

Comment: Use one or the other.