# How to use two custom directives in a single HTML element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two custom directives; namely `directiveA` and `directiveB`.
Both are custom directives performing two different actions

```
<input type="text"
       name="order_value"
       data-ng-model=""
       directive-a="{{formatText}}"
       directive-b="{{test}}"/>
```

But when I use both directives, the element is not shown. If I use only one of the directives it's working properly.

My console is displaying the following error.

> Error: error:multidir Multiple Directive Resource Contention

What should I do to be able to use both my directives on the same element?

Comment: Can you post full example code here or create fiddle demonstrating your problem?

Comment: Check console for errors. F12

Comment: Jenish, directive-a and directive-b are plugin, cannot post it fully

Comment: No errors Mr.dfsq..!

Comment: Error: error:multidir
Multiple Directive Resource Contention Mr. dfsq

Comment: are you using **angular-translate**?

Comment: No, i have not used Mr. Don.!

Comment: Are you using  attributes with the same name as the directive in your directive declaration. e.g. `<my-directive   data-my-directive="something" />` Then you might have Directive resource contention.  Or your directive attribute names are conflicting with each other?  [here is a link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27084849/angularjs-multiple-directive-resource-contention) which should help you. HTH!

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$compile/multidir?p0=someDirective&p1=translate&p2=new%2Fisolated%20scope&p3=%3Ch1%20translate%3D%22%22%20some-directive%3D%22%22%3E):

> **Description**
>
> This error occurs when multiple directives are applied to the same DOM element, and processing them would result in a collision or an unsupported configuration.
>
> To resolve this issue remove one of the directives which is causing the collision.
>
> Example scenarios of multiple incompatible directives applied to the same element include:
>
> Multiple directives requesting isolated scope.
>
> Multiple directives publishing a controller under the same name.
>
> Multiple directives declared with the transclusion option.
>
> Multiple directives attempting to define a template or templateURL.

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20609770/nested-e-directives-multiple-directives-asking-for-new-isolated-scope) you could also try to remove `replace: true` from your directives.

Answer (score -1):

After a long try, I have found the Simple Solution for the above issue.

if u have  scope set to true ie.,`scope: true` in the directive, Set to false `scope: false`